# How can i implement secure websocket client in ruby?

Tags: ruby, jruby

How can i create WSS client connection in JRuby framework?

i am using faye/websocket-driver-ruby gem for connecting and publishing message, can anyone provide the imformation about this.

Getting error,

IOError: Connection reset by peer 
sysread at org/jruby/ext/openssl/SSLSocket.java:857,

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'websocket/driver'
require 'permessage_deflate'
require 'socket'
require 'uri'
require "openssl"

class WSSClient
  DEFAULT_PORTS = { 'ws' => 80, 'wss' => 443 }

  attr_reader :url, :thread

  def initialize
    @url  = "wss://localhost:433/wss"
    @uri  = URI.parse(@url)
    @port = @uri.port || DEFAULT_PORTS[@uri.scheme]

    ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    @socket  = TCPSocket.new(@uri.host, @port)

    ssl_context.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2_client

    ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(@socket, ssl_context)
    ssl_socket.sync_close = true
    ssl_socket.connect

    @driver = WebSocket::Driver.client(self)

    @driver.add_extension(PermessageDeflate)

    str = "Hello server!"

    str = str + "\n"

    @dead = false
    @driver.on(:open) { |event|  write str } 
    @driver.on(:message) { |event| p [:message, event.data] }
    @driver.on(:close)   { |event| finalize(event) }
    @thread = Thread.new do
      @driver.parse(ssl_socket.read(1)) until @dead
    end
    @driver.start
  end

  def send(message)
    @driver.text(message)
  end

  def write(data)
    ssl_socket.write(data)
  end

  def close
    @driver.close
  end

  def finalize(event)
    p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
    @dead = true
    @thread.kill
  end
end
```

Or any other way (algorithm) to create WSS client.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. You're getting an error, but you don't say what it is. We need the absolute minimum code in the question, along with the minimum input data, and your expected output. Without that we can't run the code and confirm the error, then work on a solution that meets the required results.

Comment: Please don't use a comment to show status or information that is pertinent to the question. Edit the question and add it into it as if it'd been there all along. Readability and comprehension are extremely important on SO. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags to mark it, simply add it where it belongs in your text.

Comment: any help for this?